# How to run Huey consumer on Windows IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, windows-server, python-huey

I am working on a Django application which is deployed on a Windows Server using IIS. I want to use `Huey` to be able to run background tasks e.g. sending of emails and report generation. `Celery` does not support Windows hence my decision to use `Huey`.

According to the [documentation](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html#running-the-consumer), you can run the consumer using the following command:

`./manage.py run_huey`

My question is, how and where will I need to run this command to work with my setup i.e. Windows and IIS? It should also work when the server is restarted.

Comment: We use task scheduler in Windows to run specific tasks on our IIS web server. Here you can specify which user to run the script with and where and when etc. Very powerful.

Comment: The easiest way to install services written in Python on a Windows machine is to use Non-Sucking Service Manager (NSSM). NSSM provides a simple way to wrap a specific executable, along with arguments, and make them available as a Windows service.